# ReorderbleList with Draggable Widgets does not work

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-reorderable-listview

I have a `ReorderdableList` with 5 Widgets and each of them is `Draggable`.

The Draggable Widget works great, but it seems that this makes the `onReorder` function not work.

This is my ReorderableListView:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: ReorderableListView(
        onReorder: ((oldIndex, newIndex) {
          print('onReorder');
        }),
        onReorderStart: (index) => print('reorder start'),
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          for (final card in handCards)
            HandCard(key: ValueKey(card), card, player, handOwner),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Each Handcard returns a Draggable Widget. Is there a way to make sure both still work?

Handcard Widget:

```
class HandCard extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  HandCard(this.card, this.player, this.handOwner, {Key? key})
      : super(key: key);
  String handOwner;
  dynamic card;
  Player player;
  @override
  _HandCardState createState() => _HandCardState();
}

class _HandCardState extends ConsumerState<HandCard> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    isVisibled = true;
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    print(isVisibled);
  }

  void setVisible() {
    setState(() {
      isVisibled = true;
    });
  }

  late bool isVisibled;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var handCardPickProvider =
        ref.watch(handCardHighlightProvider(widget.card).notifier);
    var handCardPick = ref.watch(handCardHighlightProvider(widget.card));
    var gameStateProvider = ref.watch(GameStateProvider);
    var handSize = ref.watch(handSizeProvider(widget.handOwner).state);
    return Draggable<HandCard>(
      onDragStarted: () {
        // change state of current cards in hand
        handSize.state = handSize.state - 1;
      },
      onDragEnd: (details) {
        handSize.state = handSize.state + 1;
      },
      onDragCompleted: () {
        setState(() {
          isVisibled = true;
        });
      },
      data: widget,
      childWhenDragging: SizedBox.shrink(),
      feedback: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(widget.card.imageLink),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
        width: 100,
        height: 150,
        child: Stack(children: [
          (widget.card is CharacterCard)
              ? Positioned(
                  right: 0,
                  left: 60,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    width: 40,
                    height: 13,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        widget.card.power.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 10,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : const SizedBox.shrink(),
          Positioned(
              left: 2,
              child: Container(
                width: 20,
                height: 20,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                  widget.card.cost.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                )),
              ))
        ]),
      ),
      child: (isVisibled)
          ? InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                print('click');

                // If it is the counter move and the card has a counter effect we can use it
                if (gameStateProvider.gameSession!.moves.length != 0) {
                  Move currentMove = gameStateProvider.gameSession!
                      .moves[gameStateProvider.gameSession!.atMove - 1];
                  print(currentMove.moveType);
                  // Handle on counter effect
                  if (currentMove.moveType == 'on counter effect' &&
                      currentMove.toPlayer.id == widget.player.id) {
                    handCardPickProvider.highlightCard(widget.card);
                  }
                }
              },
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: [
                    (handCardPick)
                        ? BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            spreadRadius: 1,
                            blurRadius: 10)
                        : BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            spreadRadius: 0,
                            blurRadius: 0),
                  ],
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(widget.card.imageLink),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
                width: 100,
                height: 150,
                child: Stack(children: [
                  (widget.card is CharacterCard)
                      ? Positioned(
                          right: 0,
                          left: 60,
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            width: 40,
                            height: 13,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                widget.card.power.toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                  Positioned(
                      left: 2,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 20,
                        height: 20,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                          widget.card.cost.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                        )),
                      ))
                ]),
              ),
            )
          : SizedBox.shrink(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is `HandCard` is just Draggable widget ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Sheikh Handcard has also a child of Inkwell and Inkwell has a child of Container with Text.

Comment: Can you include full sample widget

Comment:  this is not sample, it is full snippet

Comment: @YeasinSheikh What would you need for a sample? I should probably just test the behavour in a simple way